# Using validator for artisan command in Lumen

Tags: validation, command, lumen, laravel-artisan

I would like to use validator for artisan commands (i.e unique user in database table). How to get validator instance inside artisan command in Lumen?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Simply add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` to class and use Validator like in Laravel.